# Sum of series involving 1+cos(n)...

Tags: sequences-and-series

$$\sum_{n=2}^\infty{1+\cos(n)\over n^2}$$

I justified that it converges absolutely by putting it less than to $\frac{1}{n^2}$ where $p=2>1$ meaning that it converges absolutely. Would this be a correct way to solve this problem?

Comment: Are you just trying to prove that the series converges? Or do you also want to find the value of the sum?

Comment: Oh yes I also need to find the value of the sum. Would I be able to use the the integral test?

Answer (score 3):

The [Clausen functions](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Clausen_function) allow for a quick and compact way to represent the sum of the series.

$$\operatorname{Sl}_{2}{\left(x\right)}=\Re{\left[\operatorname{Li}_{2}{\left(e^{ix}\right)}\right]}=\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}\frac{\cos{\left(nx\right)}}{n^2}=\frac{\pi^2}{6}-\frac{\pi x}{2}+\frac{x^2}{4}.$$

The series in question then has the sum,

$$\begin{align}
\sum_{n=2}^{\infty}\frac{1+\cos{(n)}}{n^2}
&=-1-\cos{(1)}+\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}\frac{1+\cos{(n)}}{n^2}\\
&=-1-\cos{(1)}+\operatorname{Sl}_{2}{\left(0\right)}+\operatorname{Sl}_{2}{\left(1\right)}\\
&=-1-\cos{(1)}+\frac{\pi^2}{6}+\frac{\pi^2}{6}-\frac{\pi}{2}+\frac{1}{4}\\
&=-\cos{(1)}+\frac{\pi^2}{3}-\frac{\pi}{2}-\frac34.\\
\end{align}$$

Answer (score 1):

$\displaystyle\sum_{n=2}^\infty\left\lvert{1+\cos n\over n^2}\right\rvert=\left\lvert\displaystyle\sum_{n=2}^\infty{2\cos^2 \dfrac{n}{2}\over n^2}\right\rvert=2\left\lvert\displaystyle\sum_{n=2}^\infty{\cos^2 \dfrac{n}{2}\over n^2}\right\rvert\leq\displaystyle\sum_{n=2}^\infty{2\over n^2}=\dfrac{\pi}{3}-2$

Answer (score 0):

Yes, as you say, $$\sum_{k=2}^\infty\left \lvert \frac{1+\cos(n)}{n^2}\right \lvert\leq \sum_{k=2}^\infty \frac{2}{n^2}=\frac{\pi^2}{3}-2,$$

which shows absolute convergence.

Answer (score 0):

$\newcommand{\angles}[1]{\left\langle\, #1 \,\right\rangle}
 \newcommand{\braces}[1]{\left\lbrace\, #1 \,\right\rbrace}
 \newcommand{\bracks}[1]{\left\lbrack\, #1 \,\right\rbrack}
 \newcommand{\ceil}[1]{\,\left\lceil\, #1 \,\right\rceil\,}
 \newcommand{\dd}{{\rm d}}
 \newcommand{\ds}[1]{\displaystyle{#1}}
 \newcommand{\dsc}[1]{\displaystyle{\color{red}{#1}}}
 \newcommand{\expo}[1]{\,{\rm e}^{#1}\,}
 \newcommand{\fermi}{\,{\rm f}}
 \newcommand{\floor}[1]{\,\left\lfloor #1 \right\rfloor\,}
 \newcommand{\half}{{1 \over 2}}
 \newcommand{\ic}{{\rm i}}
 \newcommand{\iff}{\Longleftrightarrow}
 \newcommand{\imp}{\Longrightarrow}
 \newcommand{\Li}[1]{\,{\rm Li}_{#1}}
 \newcommand{\pars}[1]{\left(\, #1 \,\right)}
 \newcommand{\partiald}[3][]{\frac{\partial^{#1} #2}{\partial #3^{#1}}}
 \newcommand{\pp}{{\cal P}}
 \newcommand{\root}[2][]{\,\sqrt[#1]{\vphantom{\large A}\,#2\,}\,}
 \newcommand{\sech}{\,{\rm sech}}
 \newcommand{\sgn}{\,{\rm sgn}}
 \newcommand{\totald}[3][]{\frac{{\rm d}^{#1} #2}{{\rm d} #3^{#1}}}
 \newcommand{\ul}[1]{\underline{#1}}
 \newcommand{\verts}[1]{\left\vert\, #1 \,\right\vert}$
\begin{align}&\color{#66f}{\large%
\sum_{n\ =\ 2}^{\infty}{1 + \cos\pars{n} \over n^{2}}}
=-1 - \cos\pars{1} + \sum_{n\ =\ 1}^{\infty}{1 \over n^{2}}
+ \Re\sum_{n\ =\ 1}^{\infty}{\pars{\expo{\ic}}^{n} \over n^{2}}
\\[5mm]&=-1 - \cos\pars{1} + {\pi^{2} \over 6}
+ \Re\Li{2}\pars{\expo{i}}
=-1 - \cos\pars{1} + {\pi^{2} \over 6}
-\half\,{\pars{2\pi\ic}^{2} \over 2!}\,\,{\rm B}_{2}\pars{1 \over 2\pi}
\end{align}
where $\ds{\,{\rm B}_{n}\pars{x}}$ is a
[Bernoulli Polynomial](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bernoulli_polynomials#Explicit_expressions_for_low_degrees) and $\ds{\,{\rm B}_{2}\pars{x}=x^{2} - x + {1 \over 6}}$.

> \begin{align}&\color{#66f}{\large%
> \sum_{n\ =\ 2}^{\infty}{1 + \cos\pars{n} \over n^{2}}}
> =-1 - \cos\pars{1} + {\pi^{2} \over 6}
> +\pi^{2}\,\,{\rm B}_{2}\pars{1 \over 2\pi}
> \\[5mm]&=-1 - \cos\pars{1} + {\pi^{2} \over 6}
> +\pi^{2}\bracks{\pars{1 \over 2\pi}^{2} - {1 \over 2\pi} + {1 \over 6}}
> =\color{#66f}{\large{4\pi^{2} - 6\pi - 9 \over 12} - \cos\pars{1}}
> \\[5mm]&\approx {\tt 0.4288}
> \end{align}